# Typescript: Property "navigation" does not exist on type Omit react navigation v5

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

i am trying to refactor my code in react native from javascript to typescript with this tutorial: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/typescript/#nesting-navigators
By doing types for react navigation v5 i got an error:

> Property 'navigation' does not exist on type 'Omit<{ dispatch(action:
> Readonly<{ type: string; payload?: object; source?: string; target?:
> string; }> | ((state: TabNavigationState) =>
> Readonly<...>)): void; ... 8 more ...; dangerouslyGetState():
> TabNavigationState<...>; } & ... 10 more ... &
> StackActionHelpers<...>, "dispatch" | ... 11 more ...'.

My navigation structure:
[image: navigation structure]

Expected results:

I want that i can access routes and params by Favorites Screen and can navigate to nested screen from there like this: (navigate("Root",{screen:"Something"})

Code works with javascript but by typescript there are errors with types.

My code:

types.ts

```
export type FavoriteProps = CompositeNavigationProp<
  MaterialTopTabNavigationProp<FavoritesParamList>,
  NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>
>;
```

FavoriteScreen.tsx

```
const FavoriteScreen = ({ route, navigation }: FavoriteProps) => {
  const favoriteMovies = useAppSelector((state) => state.users.favoriteMovies);
  const favoriteSeries = useAppSelector((state) => state.users.favoriteSeries);

  const changeRouteName = () => {
    if (route.name === "favMovies") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
  const [movieTab, setMovieTab] = useState(changeRouteName);
```

AppNavigator.tsx

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  ShowAll: { id: number; name: string };
...
};

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
function AppNavigator() {
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={TabScreens} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </Stack.Navigator>

export const TabScreens = ({ navigation }) => {
      <Tab.Screen name="Favorites" component={FavStackScreen} options={{ tabBarLabel: strings.favorites }} />
}
...
```

BottomTabNavigator.tsx

```
export type BottomTabParamList = {
...
  Favorites: NavigatorScreenParams<FavoritesParamList>;
  User: UserParamList;
};


export type FavoritesParamList = { favMovies: undefined; favSeries: undefined };

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator<BottomTabParamList>();

const FavTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator<FavoritesParamList>();
function FavStackScreen() {
  return (
    <FavTab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
        indicatorStyle: { backgroundColor: "tomato" },
        labelStyle: { fontSize: 14, fontFamily: "Montserrat-Bold" },
      }}
    >
      <FavTab.Screen name="favMovies" component={FavoriteScreen} options={{ tabBarLabel: strings.movies }} />
      <FavTab.Screen name="favSeries" component={FavoriteScreen} options={{ tabBarLabel: strings.series }} />
    </FavTab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Fixed by changing types to:

```
type FavoriteRouteProp = RouteProp<FavoritesParamList, "favMovies">;

type FavoriteNavigationProp = CompositeNavigationProp<
  MaterialTopTabNavigationProp<FavoritesParamList>,
  NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>
>;

export type FavoriteProps = {
  navigation: FavoriteNavigationProp;
  route: FavoriteRouteProp;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This defines the type for the `navigation` prop, not the whole props object

```
export type FavoriteProps = CompositeNavigationProp<
  MaterialTopTabNavigationProp<FavoritesParamList>,
  NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>
>;
```

If you want to define type for the props, use:

```
export type FavoriteProps = CompositeScreenProps<
  MaterialTopTabScreenProps<FavoritesParamList>,
  NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList>
>;
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript

Comment: Thank you for your answer, im using react navigation v5, by this version there is nothing like CompositeScreenProps, but i was able to do something like this:
type FavoriteRouteProp = RouteProp<FavoritesParamList, "favMovies">;

type FavoriteNavigationProp = CompositeNavigationProp<
  MaterialTopTabNavigationProp<FavoritesParamList>,
  NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>
>;

export type FavoriteProps = {
  navigation: FavoriteNavigationProp;
  route: FavoriteRouteProp;
};

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing types to:

```
type FavoriteRouteProp = RouteProp<FavoritesParamList, "favMovies">;

type FavoriteNavigationProp = CompositeNavigationProp<
  MaterialTopTabNavigationProp<FavoritesParamList>,
  NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>
>;

export type FavoriteProps = {
  navigation: FavoriteNavigationProp;
  route: FavoriteRouteProp;
};
```